# Monotonic maximal chains in a Coxeter group

Tags: coxeter-groups, co.combinatorics, order-theory

Let $(W, S)$ be a Coxeter system, and let $T = \bigcup_{w \in W, s \in S} wsw^{-1}$.  Associated to every element $t \in T$ is a unique positive root $\alpha_t \in \Phi^{+}$ considered as a vector in the standard geometric representation $V$ of $W$.  A total order on $T$ is a **reflection order** if, whenever $\alpha_{t_1} < \alpha_{t_2}$, it follows that $\alpha_{t_1} < x \alpha_{t_1} + y \alpha_{t_2} < \alpha_{t_2}$ whenever the middle term is a positive root with $x > 0, y > 0$.  (See, for example, [Bjorner and Brenti's](http://books.google.com/books?id=OsaeruFjCRsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bjorner+and+brenti&source=bl&ots=mvBZNqSImQ&sig=wNGg-W9sBQa4547x8-g1CGmbJFM&hl=en&ei=De08TOjcEoeglAeek5DqCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bjorner%20and%20brenti&f=false) book.)

Fix a reflection order and let $[u, v]$ be a Bruhat interval.  A maximal chain $u = w_0 \to w_1 \to ... \to w_m = v$ in the Bruhat order is what I'll call monotonic if $w_i w_{i-1}^{-1} > w_{i+1} w_i^{-1}$ in the reflection order.

There is a nonrecursive formula for the Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials $P_{u,v}(q)$ which implies that $P_{u,v}(0)$ is equal to the number of monotonic maximal chains in $[u, v]$.  This number is known by other means to be equal to $1$, so I know that there is a unique monotonic maximal chain; however, I can't prove this directly.  So far all I've been able to do is use the greedy algorithm to prove that at least one monotonic maximal chain exists.

Does anyone have a direct proof of this fact?

**Edit:**  No progress, but now I have a more general conjecture which I no longer know by other means is true.  Fix a sequence $a_1, ... a_m$ of odd positive integers such that $\sum_i a_i = \ell(v) - \ell(u)$.  Then there exists at most one monotonic chain (not necessarily maximal) such that $w_i w_{i-1}^{-1} \in T$ and such that $\ell(w_{i-1}) - \ell(w_i) = a_i$.

Comment: Is "monotonic" a standard term? It would seem more logical to call it "convex".

Comment: Victor, maybe that would be true if the reflection order was inherited from an order on the vertices, but it's not.  I am thinking here of plotting the sequence w_i w_{i-1}^{_1}, not of plotting the sequence w_i.

Comment: Hmm.  The original question more or less follows from Theorems 5.3.4 and 5.3.7 in Bjorner and Brenti.  But I would still be interested in a proof or a counterexample to the conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi, you may want to try to peruse these two papers:

Dyer, M. J. Hecke algebras and shellings of Bruhat intervals. Compositio Math. 89 (1993), no. 1, 91--115.

Dyer, M. J. Hecke algebras and shellings of Bruhat intervals. II. Twisted Bruhat orders. Kazhdan-Lusztig theory and related topics (Chicago, IL, 1989), 141--165, Contemp. Math., 139, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1992.

Dyer proves that Bruhat intervals are EL-shellable, and this gives the answer to your first question. As to your more general question, there may be answers to those as well (indirectly of course).