# Number of maximal chains in Bruhat order

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a formula for the number of maximal chains between two permutation in the (strong) Bruhat order?

Comment: I think your question is pretty terse -- maybe you could expand a bit?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31772/monotonic-maximal-chains-in-a-coxeter-group